# Why isn't the appBar widget constant in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why do I get an error when I try the following:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Verify Email")),
      body: Text("Needa verify that email dawg @_@"),
    );
  }
```

Error:

```
The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.
```

Why is the AppBar constructor not const?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the `AppBar` widget contains many properties that are not constant, so it can't also be constant and so it can't accept `const`.

you can think about the `AppBar` widget, as a whole sub-tree of more other widgets, and if one of them is not contact, then the whole `AppBar` is not as well.

For example, the `actions` property, accepts as an argument a `List<Widget>?` and that list can be changed dynamically, right ? so it is not constant, and so the `AppBar` is not.

I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to say, the AppBar is a sub-set of many properties that can not be constant, and this affects the `AppBar`.

Answer (score 2):

AppBar constructor isn't constant (**no const keyword leading its constructor**) and it couldn't because it have property with unknown value before compiling the program which:

```
preferredSize = 
          _PreferredAppBarSize(toolbarHeight, bottom?.preferredSize.height);
```